# Why attribute from shortcode doesn't work?

Tags: wordpress, attributes, extract, shortcode

I have such code with attribute extraction to use it in shortcode.

```
    <?php

function wpusers_shortcode( $atts ) {

    extract(shortcode_atts( array(
        'Department' => '',
        ), $atts
    )
    );


$args = array(  
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
        'key' => 'Department',
        'value' => $Department,
            ),
        )
    );

// The Query

$user_query = new WP_user_Query( $args );

// User Loop


if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {


        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';

    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}

}

add_shortcode( 'wpusers', 'wpusers_shortcode' );
?>
```

The shortcode is [wpusers Department="IEDK"].

Users are assigned to custom field Department

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doRfW.png)

But at front end I have a message - No Users Found.

When I add attr (IEDK) in the code I can see them

extract(shortcode_atts( array(
'Department' => 'IEDK',

or

```
    'key' => 'Department',
    'value' => 'IEDK',
```

Whhere can be a problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
The problem was in Uppercase of key [wpusers Department="IEDK"].
I changed to small "d" everywhere and now it works..........

Answer (score 0):

Remove extract and then try to debug with uncomment lines

```
function wpusers_shortcode( $atts ) {

    $ar = shortcode_atts( 
       array('Department' => ''),
        $atts
    );

// print_r($ar); die;


$args = array(  
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
    'key' => 'Department',
    'value' => $ar['Department'],
        ),
    )
);

 // print_r($args); die;

$user_query = new WP_user_Query( $args );

if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {


    echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';

}
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}

}
```

add_shortcode( 'wpusers', 'wpusers_shortcode' );

Comment: Debug shows me

Array ( [Department] => )

The shortcode with attr [wpusers Department="IEDK"] still doesn't work.

Comment: Array ( [meta_query] => Array ( [relation] => AND [0] => Array ( [key] => Department [value] => ) ) )